# Can we have a single scheduler with multiple databases?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I am using the Quartz 3.5.0 version of the .Net 6 application. Its multitenant application. I use a dictionary with tenantId as the key and scheduler as the value. So based on the request for a given tenant, my code picks the respective schedule and works as expected.

Now I would like to have only a single schedule but multiple tenant databases ( which have quartz-related tables).

So I create an instance of schedule and at runtime based on the tenantId value I create a new schedule and assign it to the same schedule instance.

It's working fine. but there is an issue, jobs/triggers are created in the same database ( the one which is used for the very first request( only, ideally, it should point to the respective database.

I also have posted on [Github](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/2244), But posting here for better reach.